# What are the differences and relations between a type constructor and a type operator?

Tags: programming-languages, type-theory, types-and-programming-languages

What are the definitions of a type constructor and a type operator?
What are their differences and relations?
I think a type operator is a function whose parameters are n types and return is a type. A type constructor also means the same thing. 
I use them exchangeably. But some reply used type constructor when my question (I forgot where) used type operator.
In *Types and Programming Languages* by Pierce, the index says

> type constructors, see type operators

[Ch 29 says **informally**](https://books.google.com/books?id=ti6zoAC9Ph8C&lpg=PA439&ots=ECKgBGi2WE&dq=%22We%20have%20also%20used%20type-level%20expressions%20like%20Array%20T%20and%20Ref%20T%22&pg=PA439#v=onepage&q=%22We%20have%20also%20used%20type-level%20expressions%20like%20Array%20T%20and%20Ref%20T%22&f=false) that

> these type-level functions, collectively called type operators, more formally.

Is it correct that type operators/constructors are used only and exactly to create algebraic types, and algebraic types are created only and exactly by type operators/constructors?

Is `Ref` in `Ref T` a type operator/constructor? Is `Ref T` an algebraic type?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

These sorts of terms in type theory are not always used completely consistently. However, *type operators* are generally type-level functions: that is, they take as arguments some number of types and return a single type. *Type constructors* are a specific kind of type operator for which the return type is [free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_object) in the sense that it is a new type on its arguments.

Generally speaking, if you have a type operator $T: \star \to \star$ and for any type $A : \star$, you have a type $T(A) : \star$, which is not prima facie equal to anything else, then it is called a type constructor.

For example, $\times$, $+$ and $\to$ are all type constructors. Type-level application is not, because the application of $(\lambda X . X + X)\ Y$ is reducible to $Y$, i.e. the application of the type operator is equal to some other type.

In your example, $\mathrm{Ref} : \star \to \star$ would be considered a type constructor. If by "algebraic type" you mean "algebraic data type", then $\mathrm{Ref}(T)$ is not an algebraic data type, because it's part of the type system rather than formed as a composite type out of products and sums.